# What is the best way to set same event to multiple components in android?

Tags: android, events, button

I'm developing an android app. There will a view like timetable on screen.I wanna create this view with using multiple buttons. For example like this:

- |08.30| |09.30| |10.30|
- |11.30| |12.30| |13.30|
- |14.30| |15.30| |16.30|

User will click one of buttons, and I will get button's text. I need to same event to buttons for get them text. But, there will be buttons more than 20 and I guess that process isn't useless for multiple buttons. What is the best and easiest way for set same event to buttons? Am I need to describe all buttons in java side?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Create a function and pass text of buttons as variable to it:

```
onclick()
 {
  func(Button.getText().toString());
 }

func(String s)
 {
 //do something
 }
```

you will have to override onClick of each button in the above method.

**Method 2:**

in xml define

```
<Button>
 ...
  android:onClick ="func"
 ..
</Button>
```

and in Java:

```
 func()
  {
    //Do something. 
  }
```

You wont get the text in above method.

**Method 3:**

Implement the onClickListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 ....
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
    func(button1.getText().toString());
    break; 
case R.id.button2:
      func(..)
      break;
 ....
}
```